# Returning custom status code from AWS Proxy lambda function based on certain condition, like 204, 404, but I get always 200 code as a response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, spring-cloud-function

We are using below set up for AWS Lambda function.
1 Lambda type - Proxy lambda
2 Handler -  org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker
3 Using spring cloud functions for implementing core logic
4 Tried returning below objects as a return type by setting explicitly custom http status code
APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent
Message>
I always get 200 irrespective whatever I set in the response object.

Comment: Hi, it will be much easier for us to debug this together if we can add the source code that we have to fix together!

Comment: Yes, the best way is to create a small project with bare minimum to reproduce the issue and push it to Github (or zip) so we can take a look. Here is an example of such issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/792